# How to prevent AppBar/CommandBar From Truncating Label of AppBarButton?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

Here's the Code:

```
    <Page.TopAppBar>
        <CommandBar>

            <CommandBar.SecondaryCommands>
                <AppBarButton Icon="NewWindow" Label="New"/>
                <AppBarButton Icon="OpenFile"  Label="Open"/>
                <AppBarButton Icon="Save" Label="Save"/>
                <AppBarButton Icon="Save" Label="Save As"/>
                <AppBarButton Icon="ClosePane"  Label="Close"/>
                <AppBarButton Icon="Setting" Label="Settings"/>
            </CommandBar.SecondaryCommands>

            <CommandBar.Content>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <AppBarButton Icon="Home" Label="Home" />
                    <AppBarButton Icon="Back" Label="Back"/>
                    <AppBarButton Icon="Forward" Label="Forward"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </CommandBar.Content>

        </CommandBar>
    </Page.TopAppBar>

    <Grid>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Here's a Screen Snapshot:

[image: CommandBar Problems...]

Sorry, Just can never figure out how to use CommandBar due to Large number of Windows 8 UWP books gettings passed off as Windows 10 UWP Books, and no good examples of CommandBar XAML.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to avoid using AppBar and ControlBar, and Page.TopAppBar and Page.BottomAppBar for anything.  They have too many Truncation problems.

Instead, You should embed your AppBarButton's inside of Grid Controls and then everything works perfectly.

```
<Page ...>

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid Grid.Row="0" Background="LightGray">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Orientation="Horizontal">
                <AppBarButton Icon="Home" Label="Home"/>
                <AppBarButton Icon="Back" Label="Back"/>
                <AppBarButton Icon="Forward" Label="Forward"/>
            </StackPanel>

            <AppBarButton Grid.Column="1" Icon="More">
                <AppBarButton.Flyout>
                    <MenuFlyout>
                        <MenuFlyoutItem Icon="NewWindow" Text="New"/>
                        <MenuFlyoutItem Icon="OpenFile"  Text="Open"/>
                        <MenuFlyoutItem Icon="Save"      Text="Save"/>
                        <MenuFlyoutItem Icon="Save"      Text="Save As"/>
                        <MenuFlyoutItem Icon="ClosePane" Text="Close"/>
                        <MenuFlyoutItem Icon="Setting"   Text="Settings"/>
                    </MenuFlyout>
                </AppBarButton.Flyout>
            </AppBarButton>
        </Grid>

        <!-- Content-->
        <Ellipse Grid.Row="1" Height="100" Width="100" Fill="BurlyWood"/>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

(Now if only Microsoft would move DockPanels over from WPF into UWP... )

Comment: The community toolbox has DockPanel. https://github.com/Microsoft/UWPCommunityToolkit/tree/master/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.SampleApp/SamplePages/DockPanel

Answer (score 0):

the correct way to use commandBar is this way think because it has no problems I tried with the way u used but couldn't find solution but I think this will help you as I hope :)

```
<Page.TopAppBar>
    <CommandBar ClosedDisplayMode="Compact" Background="#1FA2E1">
        <CommandBar.PrimaryCommands>

            <AppBarButton Name="xhome" Icon="Remote" Label="Home" />
            <AppBarSeparator/>
            <AppBarButton Name="xadmin" Icon="Admin" Label="Admin" />
            <AppBarSeparator/>
            <AppBarButton Name="xcontact" Icon="Contact" Label="Contact" />
            <AppBarSeparator/>
        </CommandBar.PrimaryCommands>
    </CommandBar>
</Page.TopAppBar>
```

Answer (score 0):

The natural behavior is that labels are not displayed until the `CommandBar` is opened. However, this works only for the `AppBarButtons` displayed on the right side of the control, because UWP `CommandBar` has commands only on the right according to design guidelines. But when you use `Content` for left commands, it will not work properly. As a workaround you have to bind the `IsCompact` property to the `CommandBar`'s `IsOpen` property.

First you have to add a new value converter that will just invert `bool` values:

```
class InvertBoolConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, 
                          object parameter, string language)
    {
        return !(bool)value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, 
                              object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Then you add the converter to your page as a resource:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <local:InvertBoolConverter x:Name="InvertBoolConverter" />
</Page.Resources>
```

Now add a `x:Name="TopBar"` to the `CommandBar` control and add `IsCompact` property to all `AppBarButtons` inside the `CommandBar.Content`:

```
<AppBarButton Icon="Home" Label="Home" 
    IsCompact="{Binding IsOpen, ElementName=TopBar, Converter={StaticResource InvertBoolConverter}}" />
```

The label will now display only when the `CommandBar` is open as expected.

Comment: I don’t know sounds more like a bug to me... What’s the content property for if you are not allowed to use it with out risk of truncation.

Comment: The thing is that the labels should be invisible when the command bar is closed. When you don't use CommandBar, they are always visible which goes a bit against the guidelines. The reason the bar cannot handle buttons in Content is that it doesn't "know" they are there. Content is there primarily for other uses, like some textual display, descriptions, etc.